# SPSS: select a subset of columns or rows from a matrix

Tags: matrix, spss

**How can I select a subset of columns or rows from a matrix in SPSS?**

Given the following example, I want to compute a matrix X2 containing the first two columns of X.

```
MATRIX.

   COMPUTE 
   X = {1, 2, 2;
        0, -1, 1;
        1, 1, -2}.

   * Compute new matrix X2 that contains the first two columns of X

   MAGIC CODE ;)

END MATRIX.
```

What is the syntax for matrix subsetting operations in SPSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset a matrix, so it would be simply `COMPUTE XSub = X(:,1:2).` Full example below.

```
MATRIX.
COMPUTE X = {1, 2, 2;
             0, -1, 1;
             1, 1, -2}.
COMPUTE XSub = X(:,1:2).
PRINT XSub.
END MATRIX.
```

---

To the add-on question in the comments, `1:n` basically SPSS understands as a row vector of `1 2 3 .... n`. You can create your own vector to subset the matrix though, such as `{1,3}` or `{2,2}` or `{3,1}` or whatever. The last example will return the 3rd column first and the first column second in the subsetted matrix. Example below:

```
MATRIX.
COMPUTE X = {1, 2, 2;
             0, -1, 1;
             1, 1, -2}.
COMPUTE XSub = X(:,{3,1}).
PRINT XSub.
END MATRIX.
```

Which prints out

```
Run MATRIX procedure: 

XSUB 
  2  1 
  1  0 
 -2  1 

------ END MATRIX -----
```

Comment: I knew there was going to be an easier way than the loop solution I provided! I haven't worked with `MATRIX` in years to remember all its features.

Comment: Thanks. One add-on question, if you don't mind :) How can I select non-adjacent columns, e.g. 1 and 3?

Comment: Example added @MarkHeckmann. Same idea works for selecting rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
MATRIX.
COMPUTE X = {1, 2, 3;  4, 5, 6;   7, 8, 9}.
COMPUTE Y=MAKE(NROW(X),2,0).
LOOP i=1 to NROW(Y).
  LOOP j=1 to NCOL(Y).
    COMPUTE Y(i,j)=X(i,j).
  END LOOP.
END LOOP.

PRINT X.
PRINT Y.
END MATRIX.
```

Comment: You can subset matrices, see my answer. No need for loops.